# Preferential attachment: assigning edges with a certain probability

Tags: netlogo, social-networking, agent-based-modeling

I'm trying to create a preferential attachment network with a tunable gamma parameter in Netlogo. I've posted a more general question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332789/preferential-attachement-netlogo), but I have the feeling that I do not fully understand the mechanisms behind the preferential attachment model so I will ask some other questions about it. I have the following definition for the network:

"First, each individual is assigned a number of ties according to the distribution p(k) ∝ k^−γ, where k is the number of ties a particular indiviudal has. Then, connections are made between individuals at random, beginning with those assigned the most number of ties in the first step, until either all connections assigned in step one are accounted for, or no additional connections can be made without adding to the assigned number of ties per person. "

This definition seems to indicate that nodes first have to be created, then the number of ties have to be assigned, after which these ties have to be directed to other nodes. If we take a look at the preferential attachment models in the netlogo models library, the procedure is very different. Namely, nodes are created sequentially. With the nodes selecting who to link with based on the number of already existing ties, as if they were lottery tickets.

So currently I am trying to figure out what the best procedure is to create the network with the tunable gamma. To make the first described procedure work I should create a set of nodes and then assign the number of ties given the distribution. How is this done?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Based on the answer @JenB has given. I want to make sure I am understanding it correctly. If I have the following code:

```
to create-new-nodes [n]
    clear-all
    ask patches [ set pcolor white ]
    create-nodes n [
    set color red
    set shape "circle"
  ]

    reset-ticks
end

to wire-pref-attach
  create-new-nodes num-nodes
  set friends [;;distribution should be included here?]
  ask nodes
[ let new-edges friends - count my-edges
  if new-edges > 0
  [ let candidates other nodes with [ count my-edges < friends ]
    create-edges-with n-of min (list new-edges count candidates) candidates
    [ hide-link ]
  ]
]
  radial-layout
end
```

The `set friends` command should include the distribution with the tunable gamma, right? How is this achieved? By using a weighted rnd extension? Also, I still don't fully understand the meaning of both *A* and *m*. Anyone care to explain in the most basic language possible? I understand that *A* is defined as the inherent attractiveness and m is the number of edges a new node creates, but how do high (low) values of these parameters translate to the outcome of the network structure?

EDIT2:

Received advice from a different source to use the following 'hack' to correctly program the network algorithm. The code should have the structure:

1. Let k_i be the degree of node i
2. Let a variable D (for denominator) be the sum of all (k_i)^(gamma)
3. Iterate on the nodes; for each node i, create an edge if random-float 1.0 <= k_i ^ gamma / D

this is considered to be a hack, because the model creates on average one link per turn. It does not create exactly one link per turn.

I've tried to code this in the following way:

```
to wire-pref-attach
  create-new-nodes num-nodes
  let connect? False
  let denominator (count nodes * k_i ^ gamma) ;;HOW TO DETERMINE K_i? 
  let numerator (k_i ^ gamma)
  ask other nodes [
    if (numerator / denominator) >= random-float 1.0 [
     set connect? true
      create-link-from myself
    ]
  ]
    radial-layout
end
```

However, I still don't understand how I should determine k_i and how this relates to variables m and A mentioned in the comments below.

Comment: copied relevant bits of my answer to your other question below

Comment: Yes, this is where you would change the code if you were drawing from an arbitrary distribution. BUT if you can understand the algorithm in the paper I described in my answer, then you should use THAT algorithm, not the arbitrary distribution one. This is a network science question, rather than a programming one.

Answer (score 2):

That 'definition' is the general algorithm for creating a network with an arbitrary degree distribution. That is, you assign each node an intended or target degree from whatever distribution you want. Then, you simply create links until that target degree is reached. Has nothing to do with preferential attachment, except that the distribution you have provided is the distribution that arises when the preferential attachment mechanism is used.

I think you need the algorithm described in Dorogovtsev et al (2000) Structure of Growing Networks with Preferential Linking (see https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.85.4633 if you have access). In the Barabasi-Albert algorithm, the nodes in the existing network for the new node to attach to are selected with probability proportional to degree (or *k* in your question). In the extended algorithm, each node has an inherent attractiveness *A* and the probability of selection is instead *A+k*.

Equation 12 in the paper describes the relationship between the exponent (your parameter gamma as: gamma = 2 + A/m where *m* is the the number of edges being attached with each node.

Also see [NetLogo Efficient way to create fixed number of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967388/netlogo-efficient-way-to-create-fixed-number-of-links) for potential code to generalise.

Comment: Thanks! I think I am starting to understand this network structure bit by bit. Still have some remaining questions, though. See edit.

Comment: m is an integer you select depending on how dense you want the network to be. Average degree will be 2m. In your case you probably want m to be a slider for the user to select. Then from m and gamma (also a slider), calculate the value of A from formula I gave. Then you can use preferential attachment method rather than arbitrary degree distribution method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'm really appreciate it! But I think I'm totally lost on this one. Could you maybe share some literature on this subject I can read through. Or, even better, care to give an example (or provide preliminary version) of how I should program this network structure that I can expand? I'm currently working on using this network structure in a model I've made for my thesis and time is slowly running out, unfortunately.

Comment: You need to read two papers. The Barabasi-Albert one that describes preferential attachment (or any network science book really) and the paper I have already cited that describes the extension for inherent fitness. Until you understand the algorithm that you are trying to program, you won't be able to program it. Thesis for what degree? What is your background? Stackoverflow is not set up to answer this type of question but I can discuss it with you in chat if I can figure out how to do that.

Comment: For my master's degree in Sociology. So I math-game isn't very strong, nor do I know much about network theory, making this really hard to understand. I've edited my original post with some advice I received elsewhere. If you don't see stackoverflow fit for this discussion please let me know where we can continue this discussion.

Comment: Not sure if this will work - go to chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/148220/elc-and-jenb-re-preferential-attachment-algorithms?tab=access